# Recursively checking for odd or even

Tags: python, recursion

In this code:

```
def is_even(x):
  if x == 0:
    return True
  else:
    return is_odd(x-1)

def is_odd(x):
  return not is_even(x)

print(is_even(2))
print(is_odd(2))
```

I keep going through this in my head and wondering how it's working.  It seems to me that eventually `x` in `is_even(x)` will return `True` every time.  However, when I run the code, it works perfectly fine and returns `True` and `False` appropriately.  Can someone explain how that's happening?

I understand the basic concept of recursion and fully understand how the famous factorial example works.  However, this one is hard for me to wrap my head around.

Feeling inept right now...

Comment: You have a base case. Seems fine to me.

Comment: But don't try these approaches on negative numbers ... :)

Comment: Trying writing the outputs on a piece of paper

Comment: If you call `is_even(3)`, one of the recursive calls eventually executed will be `is_even(0)`, but while that recursive call will return True, that's not what `is_even(3)` will return.

Comment: Go through the code step by step. It’s really not difficult to understand.

Comment: @MSeifert just change `x` to `abs(x)` everywhere and OP's good to go.

Comment: `is_even(1)` will never return `True`

Comment: The basic idea is "something is even if the number before it is odd OR it is zero', and 'something is even if it is not odd"

Comment: Considering that the base case returns 0, think about how many times the `not` is executed for even and odd kinds of numbers. For example, for `is_even(2)`, there is a base case of `True`, but `not` is executed an even number of times.

Comment: @PeterWood, isn't that a good thing given `1` is in fact odd.

Comment: @AChampion Yes, `is_even(1)` should return `False`, but it is easy to see why it does so, which is what OP was struggling with.

Comment: Well, that's one way to test if a number is even or odd...

Comment: Why do you think `is_even` will always return `True`? If you haven't even worked out your thinking enough to actually write it down for us, then it's impossible for us to explain where it went wrong. Which leaves us asking if you even really thought it through. As software developers, we *must* have the ability to critique our own thinking (or sometimes the lack of our thinking). I'm afraid I must downvote for not doing so. Also, [what did the duck say](http://hwrnmnbsol.livejournal.com/148664.html)?

Answer (score 9):

It always helps to decompose a recurrence relation till you find its base case.

```
is_even(2) => return is_odd(1) 
           => return not is_even(1) 
           => return not is_odd(0)
           => return not not is_even(0)
           => return not not True
           => return True            ---- (1)
```

```
is_odd(2) => return not is_even(2) 
          => return not True       [from (1)] 
          => return False
```

In general, from your recurrence functions, it is easy to observe that `is_even(n)` will return `[not not not ... n times] True`, while `is_odd(n)` will return `[not not not ... n - 1 times] True`. So the number of `not`s and hence the final expression depend on `n` (aha!). Well, that's certainly a roundabout way of asking whether

```
n % 2 == 0
```

Answer (score 5):

Add a couple of `print` statements and you will see what it is doing:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def is_even(x):
    if x == 0:
        print('True')
        return True
    else:
        return is_odd(x-1)

def is_odd(x):
    print('not', end=' ')
    return not is_even(x)

>>> is_even(5)
not not not not not True
False
>>> is_odd(5)
not not not not not not True
True
```

Comment: The question wasn't tagged python-3.x so probably better to include a `from __future__ import print_function` at the top.

Answer (score 3):

Like in most cases it might be helpful to include simply `print`s to follow the execution:

```
def is_even(x):
    print('check if {} is even'.format(x))
    if x == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return is_odd(x-1)

def is_odd(x):
    print('check if {} is odd'.format(x))
    return not is_even(x)
```

Then in your cases:

```
>>> print(is_even(2))
check if 2 is even
check if 1 is odd
check if 1 is even
check if 0 is odd
check if 0 is even
True

>>> print(is_odd(2))
check if 2 is odd
check if 2 is even
check if 1 is odd
check if 1 is even
check if 0 is odd
check if 0 is even
False
```

So basically it decrements the number until it's `0`. The point is just how many `not`s have been accumulated in the `is_odd` calls. If it's an even number of `not`s then the result will be `True`, otherwise `False`.

Answer (score 2):

That's true; the recursion is supposed to end inside `is_even`.

And when that will happen, you'll know that the number you have is `0`.

Now lets go backwards. This final state will be achieved by two cases - direct call to `is_even(0)` or a call from `is_odd(0)`. In the first case - the result is all good. In the second - the result will be returned to the `is_odd` function, negated, and therefore will be falsy - giving a correct result.

Now, here the missing piece comes - the recursion: in order to reach this state, we need to decrease the argument each time, passing it through the opposite function - and that's exactly what we get with `return is_odd(x-1)`.

---

**Note:** eventually this recursion leads to a chain of negations of the value `True` returned by the `is_even`. This chain is of length `x` where `x` is your number, and therefore odd or even in correspondence.

Therefore, the following code will do the same (lacking the `is_odd` nice side effect):

```
def is_even (x):
    res = True
    while x:
        res = not res
        x -= 1
    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that all the other answers are great but potentially the easiest way to understand the problem is how many times the answer will get "not"ed. Every time it passes through the is_odd function a not will be added on to the final answer. True will always be returned but for even numbers, there will always be an even number of nots which cancel each other out, but for odd numbers they will always have an odd number of nots and therefore return false.